# sed complex string (single and double quotes & / space...)

Tags: string, sed, replace, quotes

Hollo, i have researched a lot but never find a solution that fits what i need.

I have to replace the original xml line:

```
<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %T " prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>
```

with a modificated xml line:

```
<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %T %{i,Proxy-Remote-User}" prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>
```

I tried making 2 variables. here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
MOD=`more /aplicaciones/users/t682213/alvaro/mod`
XML=`more /aplicaciones/users/t682213/alvaro/xml`
sed "s#$XML#$MOD#g" test2
```

But i get something duplicated like this:

```
/aplicaciones/users/t682213/alvaro$ sed "s#$XML#$MOD#g" test2

<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t <access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %T " prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>quot;%r<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %T " prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>quot; %s %b <access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %T " prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>quot;%{i,Referer}<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %T " prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>quot; <access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %T " prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>quot;%{i,User-Agent}<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %T " prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>quot; %T %{i,Proxy-Remote-User}" prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>
```

Please i need help, i want to replace a very complex string with another very complex string.

Comment: No. Don't use Regexes on XML. Use a XML parser then replace the node attribute as needed. Or you could use XSLT which let's one write tree transducers.

Answer (score 1):

Dan D. is right. Manipulating XML using regular expressions is an evil hack that works in some cases, but it can quickly become a maintance nightmare. Nevertheless, if you are really confident that for some reasons (like having no XML parser availabel) you just *have* to use sed for that task, I provide an answer to your question (referencing another SO question).

You need to *escape* the strings from the file. In this case, the trouble arises from the character `&` in the replacement string which means *put the whole match in here*. See [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern) for suggestions on how to escape the search and the replace pattern.

Comment: thank you very much, i will see for scaping "&", if i find the solution i will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I GOT THE SOLUTION

As Michael mention, what was the problem was the &, so i escaped the & in the two text variables, (the MOD and the XML)

**here is my result**, (if you find problems with regex in sed, like /, "", &, **try this**)

first of all i create two texts one for the xml string that i want to replace (xml), and the other text with the xml string that i want to replace with (mod)

here are the two texts:

**xml** (with & escape: **\&**)

```
<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t \&quot;%r\&quot; %s %b \&quot;%{i,Referer}\&quot; \&quot;%{i,User-Agent}\&quot; %T " prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>
```

mod (with & escape: **\&**)

```
<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t \&quot;%r\&quot; %s %b \&quot;%{i,Referer}\&quot; \&quot;%{i,User-Agent}\&quot; %T %{i,Proxy-Remote-User}" prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>
```

i created a test txt to simulate de complete xml where i want to work after, called **test2**

```
<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %T " prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>
HOLA
ADIOS
```

And finally create a shell script that makes the change with sed: **(its very importand to use # instead / and " " instead ' ' )**

```
#!/bin/bash
MOD=`more /aplicaciones/users/t682213/alvaro/mod`
XML=`more /aplicaciones/users/t682213/alvaro/xml`
sed "s#$XML#$MOD#" test2 >> test3
```

finally the script generate a test3 text that is modificated correctly:

```
<access-log pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{i,Referer}&quot; &quot;%{i,User-Agent}&quot; %T %{i,Proxy-Remote-User}" prefix="access_${jboss.server.name}" suffix=".log"/>
HOLA
ADIOS
```